# Where are credentials stored for SSIS data sources?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm setting up a development machine in which I need to maintain an SSIS package created by another developer.  I can't get the package to run on this new machine, either in Visual Studio or as a SQL Server job.  The most helpful message comes from Profiler:

`Login failed for user 'MyUserName'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]`

I know what the password should be, but I can't find where to set it.

To debug this, I've tried two ways of modifying the credentials to specify a different user, but the different user name is not being used in the connection attempts.

First I tried modifying the data source properties in Visual Studio.

[image: VS screenshot]

Then I tried modifying the package config.

```
Data Source=.\SQL2014;User ID=DifferentUserName;Initial Catalog=dbname;...
```

The original user name is still being logged in Profiler, so I'm wondering where else to look for the credentials.

Comment: Is the connection manager using any expressions? Is the package using any configurations? How is the package being exexuted?

Comment: it is encrypted  under DTS:Property><DTS:Password DTS:Name="Password"

Comment: @Martin, there are no expressions as far as I can tell.  There are variables, but these don't relate to the connection credentials (they are rowCount and headerKey, which we log). I've tried running the package in VS2012 (right click, Execute Package) and as a job step (where I specify the config file mentioned in the question).